# Flutter ListView doesn't change when setState() is called

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to using Flutter/Dart and I'm having a hard time understanding why the following code doesn't update the ListView contents when _updateResults() calls setState(). I've even added a print statement to display the contents of `_results` and I can see that items are being added to the list but the display never updates.

```
class SearchHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  createState() => _SearchHomePageState();
}

class _SearchHomePageState extends State<SearchHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _results = <Widget>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _results.add(Text("testing"));
  }

  void _updateResults(String text) {
    setState(() {
      _results.add(Text(text));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            onSubmitted: (String text) {
              _updateResults(text);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(children: _results)
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

If I change the ListView portion to be like:

```
Expanded(
   child: ListView(children: _results.toList())
)
```

Then it will work and I'm not sure why because it was already a list. What exactly is going on here and why doesn't it work with just ListView?

Comment: can you show the error you're getting in the console? Or is it simply not working?

Answer (score 5):

From StatefulWidget [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html):

> StatefulWidget instances themselves are immutable and store their mutable state either in separate State objects that are created by the createState method, or in objects to which that State subscribes [...]

From [this](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-for-beginners-immutability-and-the-value-of-val-78ab45b60b57) article:

> By definition, immutable means that, once created, an object/variable can’t be changed. So, instead of changing a property of an object, you have to make a copy (or clone) of the entire object and in the process, change the property in question.

You created the ListView with the same array. You changed the content of the array, but you did not change the reference to that object.
That's why it works when you use `_results.toList()` because `.toList()` "creates a [List] containing the elements of this [Iterable]".

Another solution could be:

```
setState(() {
  _results = List.from(_results)
    ..add(Text(text));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't work because you are adding a new item to the existing list and not creating a new list.

this will fix your problem:

```dart
class SearchHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  createState() => _SearchHomePageState();
}

class _SearchHomePageState extends State<SearchHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _results = <Widget>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _results.add(Text("testing"));
  }

  void _updateResults(String text) {
    setState(() {
      _results = [..._results, Text(text)];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            onSubmitted: (String text) {
              _updateResults(text);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView(children: _results)
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

note: it's better to do the follwing rather than creating widgets and saving them in an array:

```dart
class SearchHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  createState() => _SearchHomePageState();
}

class _SearchHomePageState extends State<SearchHomePage> {
  List<String> _results = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _results.add("testing");
  }

  void _updateResults(String text) {
    setState(() {
      _results = [..._results, text];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            onSubmitted: (String text) {
              _updateResults(text);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView(
          children: _results.map((v) => Text(v)).toList(),
        )),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

when you call .toList() it will create a new list instance (copy of your old list)

Answer (score 0):

```
      ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: _results.map((one) => one).toList(),
      ),

      ListView.builder(

        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _results.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => _results[index],
      ),
```

If You strive to getting your output as per your requirement then you have to change your code like above instand of below code:

```
Expanded(
   child: ListView(children: _results.toList()))
```

Please put any one listview from both...

Comment: Instead map, you can use `children: _results.cast<Widget>()` to avoid unnecessary iterations